# Unity - can't see canvases after updating to 5.3.5? But they are still there?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have just updated Unity from 5.3.1 to 5.3.5 as I am trying to build for Android and ran into problems with 5.3.1. Thankfully my entire project after importing still works (the scripts seem to be running just as they had before) however Im having an odd problem-

All my canvases are not appearing at runtime. I know the canvases are still there because I can see them in my scene (picture below) and no errors are drawn but it is as they are disabled or hidden.

Has anyone else experienced this? Why are my canvases "disabled" n 5.3.5? How can I fix this?

[image][image]

Comment: How many items you keep in your dock!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its this Unity bug, which should be fixed in 5.3.6 (but that is not out yet)

For me world canvas+cardboard works in 5.3.4f1, but not in any later versions or patch releases.

Unity bug tracker link for this issue:
World space canvas aren't rendered to render texture
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/world-space-canvas-arent-rendered-to-render-texture

Comment: Just reverted to 5.3.4 and canvases work again. My problem is Im trying to build for Android - with 5.3.4 I get the no module loaded again for Android. when I click "open download page" I get directed to a page that doesn't exist anymore - is there any way to build for android?

Comment: When you install unity, select [x] android platform from there. Also saw in the forums that this canvas bug is fixed in the patch release 5.3.5p5 (which is not out yet)